# HTML Block Formatting

Tags: html

I am taking an HTML / Web Design course and just started it the other week. Now this isn't the first time I've done HTML, but I don't really remember much of it. I am trying to put some Java Code onto one of my web pages, as a way of "showing my recent accomplishments".

So what I'm looking for is a way to format a block of text, so that it retains all its white space / tabs.

```
<BODY>
    <h1> Java Code Samples! </h1>

    <P> Hello, and welcome to the java code sample section of my site. Here I will put some </P>
    <P> random samples of code that I have written and projects that I have completed </P>
    <br />
    <h3 align="left"> These are some random methods: </h3>
    <p>
    <i> //Returns index of item in other array
        //Efficiency ( O(N) )
        public static int getOtherIndex(String searchString, College[] searchTarget)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < searchTarget.length; i++)
                if(searchString.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(searchTarget[i].nameOfSchool.trim()))
                    return i;

            return -1;
        }
    </i>
    </p>

</BODY>
```

I am trying to format the method in a way that retains the initial white space, but while using the italics tag to make it stand out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<pre>` tag to do this.

It keeps the formatting the same.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/JC9ej/

Fyi... better to style the `p` tag than to use an `i` for italics.